# why event.target.value is undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events

I wrote a function as follow

```
var getVal = function(event){
   var amount = event.target.value;
   console.log(amount);
 }
```

Dom

```
<input id='myInp' type='text' onclick='getVal()'/>
```

Sometimes I can get the value just 1 click but sometimes I have to click several times to trigger the event.... Can any one tell me why? This happened on my React.JS application and my ReactNative project as well. Try a lot of time but useless at all...

Many thanks

Comment: `getVal(event)` pass the event too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short possible solution is to pass the `event` object:

```
<input id='myInp' type='text' onclick='getVal(event)'/>
```

I would rather suggest you to go unobtrusive instead of inline event handlers:

```
var el = document.querySelector('#myInp');
el.addEventListener('click', getVal);
```